# IEEE conference papers some maths symbols are not correctly displayed (matrix) and all references are replaced by?

Tags: bibliographies, matrices

I have typed my code on other templates It works well, now that I have to use another template particularly for **IEEE Cconference** here is the link [IEEE TEMPLATE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6RXQUqktUOc3hGWENVSElUX2c/view?usp=sharing)to the whole project (I would be gratefull for those who could help) all my references are displayed [?] and matrix is not correctly displayed it works fine on other template but not on **IEEE** here is my code :
      **edited**

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        **edited: added packages**
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
        \setcellgapes{1pt}
        \makegapedcells
        \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
        \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
        \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
         \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1} %interligne
         \setlength{\parskip}{0.3cm}
 \usepackage{array, multirow, makecell}
         \setcellgapes{1pt}
        \makegapedcells
        \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
        \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
        \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
           \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1} %interligne
          \setlength{\parskip}{0.3cm}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

                     \hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
                     \newcounter{savefootnote}
                     \begin{document}

                      % paper title
                     \title{BB BB BB HH GG YH}
                     % make the title area
                     \maketitle

                   BLABLA ${H'}$ training VVV $\{ (x_{k},y_{k}) 
                      \}_{k=1}^{H'}$ , each BHHU JJDD JHDJD JSSKes where 
                             $x_{k}\in  \mathbb{R}^{O}$ as an ouHYYY $ y_{k} 
                           \in \{1, -1\}$, GTTows:

             \begin{equation}
             \centering
             \label{equation2}

            \begin{bmatrix}
            0 & Y^{T} \\[0.3em]
            Y & \Omega+ I/\gamma
            \end{bmatrix}
            \begin{bmatrix}
            b  \\[0.3em]
           \alpha 
            \end{bmatrix}
            =\begin{bmatrix}
            0  \\[0.3em]
            \vec{e} 
            \end{bmatrix}

            \end{equation}
                       \subsection{FF}
                       Suppose $O$-di as $ X \in  \mathbb{R} ^{O} $,
                      CRRR $D =(O+N)$ the HHHrns $ \{ (x_{k},y_{k}) 
                        \}_{k=1}^{H}$, each patternYYYYYY $x_{k}\in  
                         \mathbb{R}^{D}$ as an oJJJJJJJ $ y_{k} \in \{1, 
                            -1\}$,  \cite{suykens1999least,knuth1998art, 
                            guan2002incremental, zhou2002hybrid, 
                          chao2008incremental, liu2008incremental, 
                             agrawal2008incremental, wang2012evolving, 
                                 liu2015neural, friedman2001elements, 
                                  utgo1994improved, shah2004sequential, 
                                        hariharan:2013} :
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
                             (HERE IS A PRBLM)
            \begin{equation}
            \centering
            \label{equation1}

          \begin{bmatrix}
          0 & Y^{T} \\[0.3em]
          Y & \Omega+ I/\gamma
          \end{bmatrix}
          \begin{bmatrix}
          b  \\[0.3em]
          \alpha 
          \end{bmatrix}
          =\begin{bmatrix}
          0  \\[0.3em]
          \vec{e} 
          \end{bmatrix}

            \end{equation}     

                With  $\alpha=[\alpha_{1},..,\alpha_{L}]^{T}$,  $Y=
               [y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}..,y_{H}]^{T}$, $ \vec{e}=[1,1,1,..,1]^{T}$ 
                  , $\Omega_{ij}=y_{i}y_{j}\varphi_{2}
                    (x_{j})=y_{i}y_{j}k_{2}(x_{i},x_{j})$ where $j <= H$ and 
                       $i>=1$
                  NOT well: 

            \begin{equation}
            \centering
            \label{equation1}
            y(x)=sign (W_{O}^{T}\varphi_{1}(x_{O})+W_{D}^{T}\varphi_{2}
            (x_{D})+b)\\
                = sign(\sum_{i=1}^{H'}\alpha_{i}y_{i}K_{1}
                    (x_{iO},x_{O})+\sum_{k=1}^{H}\alpha''_{k}y_{k}K_{2}
                     (x_{kD},x_{D})+b) 
            \end{equation}
                %\end{thebibliography}
                     \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
                   %\bibliography{myfile}
 \end{document}
```

here is the matrix with the same code on other template correctly displayed.

[image]

Comment: t solve your problem we need to know, what you have in preamble of your document ... so please provide complete small document beginning with  `\documentclass{....}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Zarko soory I forget it when coping my code yeah `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} `( I have added it) and for end doc exists already

Comment: Try adding packages amsmath and amsfonts.

Comment: @JohnKormylo okey thank you I add \usepackage {amsmath} \usepackage {amsfonts} only !

Comment: please, clean-up your preamble and remove all repeated commands definition and twice loaded packages. also format your code such, that it be more easy to read.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thank you am very grateful :) for matrix is okey it is displayed correctly now  just this long equation  for `y(x) = sign(..)`  when  I put \\ to return back it generates error and the paper is divided vertically how to fix the equation please ! but for my references  still [?]

Comment: You have a \end(array} with no \begin{array}.  (This is out or order now)

Comment: If all citation call-outs are rendered as `[?]`, it means that you did not run BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs.

Comment: @Mico I did more than one time :|

Comment: @mirette - And, did you uncomment the instruction `\bibliography{myfile}`? (Presumably, `myfile.bib` contains the raw bib entries, right?) Without a `\bibliography` instruction, there will be no bibliography -- and no proper citation call-outs to formatted bibliographic entries either.

Comment: @Mico what you mean please do you talk about the last four lines `%\end{thebibliography}
                     \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
                   %\bibliography{myfile}` have I to uncomment the last one !!?

Comment: @mirette - You asked, "have I to uncomment the last [line]"? Answer: Yes.

Comment: it works @Mico thank you am veryyy gratefull :) thank you really :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- never put `\centering` in equation environment
- `equation` is only for one-line equation, if you like to have in more line, you had to use one of `amsmath` environments like `align`, `split`, `multline`  ...
- in preamble are missed packages for bold math fonts and also `amsmath` ...
- enclosing `bmatrix` in array for add `{` before matrix is superfluous

cleaned *mwe* with added missed packages is:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}
    \setcellgapes{1pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1} %interligne
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.3cm}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bbm} % <-- added
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\newcounter{savefootnote}

\begin{document}
\title{BB BB BB HH GG YH}
\maketitle

BLABLA ${H'}$ training VVV $\{ (x_{k},y_{k})\}_{k=1}^{H'}$ , each BHHU JJDD JHDJD JSSKes where $x_{k}\in  \mathbb{R}^{O}$ as an ouHYYY $ y_{k} \in \{1, -1\}$, GTTows:
    \begin{equation}\label{equation2}
\left\{
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & Y^{T} \\
        Y & \Omega+ I/\gamma
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        b  \\
        \alpha
    \end{bmatrix}
    =\begin{bmatrix}
        0  \\
        \vec{e}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \right.
    \end{equation}

\subsection{FF}
Suppose $O$-di as $ X \in  \mathbb{R} ^{O} $, CRRR $D =(O+N)$ the HHHrns $ \{ (x_{k},y_{k}) \}_{k=1}^{H}$, each patternYYYYYY $x_{k}\in \mathbb{R}^{D}$ as an oJJJJJJJ $ y_{k} \in \{1, -1\}$,
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                             (HERE IS A PRBLM)
    \begin{equation}\label{equation1}
\left\{
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & Y^{T} \\
        Y & \Omega+ I/\gamma
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        b  \\[0.3em]
        \alpha
    \end{bmatrix}
    =\begin{bmatrix}
        0  \\[0.3em]
        \vec{e}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \right.
    \end{equation}
With  $\alpha=[\alpha_{1},..,\alpha_{L}]^{T}$,  $Y=
               [y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}..,y_{H}]^{T}$, $ \vec{e}=[1,1,1,..,1]^{T}$
                  , $\Omega_{ij}=y_{i}y_{j}\varphi_{2}
                    (x_{j})=y_{i}y_{j}k_{2}(x_{i},x_{j})$ where $j <= H$ and
                       $i>=1$
NOT well:
    \begin{multline}\label{equation1}
y(x)=sign (W_{O}^{T}\varphi_{1}(x_{O})+W_{D}^{T}\varphi_{2}
            (x_{D})+b)\\
    = sign(\sum_{i=1}^{H'}\alpha_{i}y_{i}K_{1}(x_{iO},x_{O})\\
        + \sum_{k=1}^{H}\alpha''_{k}y_{k}K_{2}(x_{kD},x_{D})+b)
    \end{multline}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for maths equations it is okey ! :) just references thank you for your help

Comment: i complete now my answer, i not succeed to do all in one step (always found something new to repair :-( )

Comment: @mirette - Your document requires a `\bibliography` instruction if you expect LaTeX&BibTeX to generate a formatted bibliography (and citation call-outs to entries in the formatted bibliography)...

Comment: am not an expert a bit weired but there is    `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` this by default soory if I did not uderstand @Mico is this the bib that I need !!

Comment: @mirette - LaTeX and BibTeX require **both** a `\bibliographystyle` directive and a `\bibliography` directive. The code you posted is lacking a (functioning) `\bibliography` directive.

Comment: thank you for all of you guys it works finally thank you